# Cleanest way to upload image to S3 from Mac OS X app?

Tags: macos, amazon-s3

I have been trying to find an easy solution to upload a small image (500px) to S3 from a Mac app I am building.

The mac app is an OS X version of an iOS app I have already built. The only interaction I need to have with AWS is to upload images so I am just looking for the best practice method for doing this.

Is creating a PHP script to do the job on the EC2 instance the best way to go about this since there isn't an AWS SDK for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an OSXified version of the iOS SDK [here](https://github.com/imperiumsage/aws-sdk-ios). I have added a scheme to build only the modules (AWSCore, AWSCognito and AWSS3) you need for S3 interactions. Once you build, locate the Products directory in finder and you should see the 3 .framework files you will need to add to your OSX project.
From that point onwards it is the same as using the iOS library, instructions for which are provided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) (Getting started with Swift/Objective-C sections).

When using in your own project make sure you add a build phase for copy files and add these frameworks there. Lastly turning on codesigning will prevent you from having to interact with Keychain Access everytime you run your app.